# Spring Data Cassandra how to set finite number of connection retries?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am currently implementing a spring boot microservice, which is persisting data to a single Cassandra database node. I need to be able to set the number of retries if the connection to the database is lost and the number of milliseconds between the retries in the microservice config file. I am using "spring-boot version 1.5.6" and spring-data-cassandra version 1.5.6". I was able to set the number of milliseconds between retries by creating cluster of type `CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean` and passing a custom reconnection policy in the `cluster.setReconnectionPolicy()` method. But I am not able to set the number of retries with a custom retry policy. If understood correctly the retry policy handles only the case in which a query is made, but in my case I need to set the number of retries in all times no matter if a query is made or not. After a couple of days of research I was able to produce an ugly hack which basically uses a custom `ReconnectionSchedule` and stops the spring boot application after certain conditions are met in the `nextDelayMs()` method. Nevertheless I continued to look in the source code in debug mode and I saw that a `NoHostAvailableException` exception is thrown by the `ControlConnection`. So I checked the datastax official documentation regarding [Control connection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/control_connection/), and I found

> Coming soon…

So could someone please show me how to correctly implement a way of stopping my cassandra driver of trying to reconnect to the node after a predefined number of retries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.cassandra-java-config) at 9.3.1.

Maybe you can do something like trying to open a session each x second until a timeout expired or a session is successful created.